# Configuring L2TP/IPSec on Cisco Router 2911

Tags: ipsec, cisco-vpn, l2tp

Hi all, I have problem with L2TP/IPSec configuration in Cisco Router 2911 . I cannot connect via Windows 7,8.1,10 build in vpn client.

#### Here is my config :

```
aaa new-model 
aaa authentication ppp L2TP-LOGIN local     
username l2tpuser password cisco     
! 
vpdn enable     
vpdn-group L2TP-GR     
description L2TP over IPSec    
accept-dialin     
protocol l2tp     
virtual-template 2    
exit 

no l2tp tunnel authentication     
session-limit 20 

exit 
! 
ip local pool L2TP-POOL 172.16.23.100 172.16.23.200     
interface Virtual-Template2     
description L2TP over IPSec Template     
ip unnumbered FastEthernet0/1     
peer default ip address pool L2TP-POOL     
no keepalive     
ppp authentication ms-chap-v2 L2TP-LOGIN     
ppp mtu adaptive     
exit 
! 
crypto isakmp enable     
crypto logging session     
crypto isakmp invalid-spi-recovery    
! 
crypto isakmp policy 20     
encr 3des     
authentication pre-share     
group 2     
hash md5    
exit 
! 
crypto keyring L2TP-KEY     
pre-shared-key address 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 key cisco123cisco     
exit 
! 
crypto isakmp profile L2TP-PROF     
keyring L2TP-KEY     
match identity address 0.0.0.0     
exit 
! 
crypto ipsec transform-set L2TP-TRSET esp-3des esp-md5-hmac     
mode transport     
exit 
! 
crypto dynamic-map DYN-L2TP-MAP 10     
set isakmp-profile L2TP-PROF     
set transform-set L2TP-TRSET     
set nat demux     
exit     
! 
crypto map L2TP-MAP 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic DYN-L2TP-MAP     
! 
interface gi0/0    
description WAN    
crypto map L2TP-MAP     
exit 
!
```

What's the problem? Where am I wrong?

#### Updated

```
.Apr  3 08:16:16.610: ISAKMP (1070): received packet from 192.168.7.92 dport 
500 sport 500 Global (R) QM_IDLE
.Apr  3 08:16:16.610: ISAKMP: set new node -1169728138 to QM_IDLE
.Apr  3 08:16:16.610: crypto_engine: Decrypt IKE packet
.Apr  3 08:16:16.610: crypto_engine: Generate IKE hash
.Apr  3 08:16:16.610: ISAKMP:(1070): processing HASH payload. message ID = 
3125239158
.Apr  3 08:16:16.610: ISAKMP:(1070): processing DELETE payload. message ID = 
3125239158
.Apr  3 08:16:16.610: ISAKMP:(1070):peer does not do paranoid keepalives.

.Apr  3 08:16:16.610: ISAKMP:(1070):deleting node -1169728138 error FALSE 
reason "Informational (in) state 1"
.Apr  3 08:16:16.610: ISAKMP (1070): received packet from 192.168.7.92 dport 
500 sport 500 Global (R) QM_IDLE
.Apr  3 08:16:16.610: ISAKMP: set new node -1213364179 to QM_IDLE
.Apr  3 08:16:16.610: crypto_engine: Decrypt IKE packet
.Apr  3 08:16:16.610: crypto_engine: Generate IKE hash
.Apr  3 08:16:16.610: ISAKMP:(1070): processing HASH payload. message ID = 
3081603117
.Apr  3 08:16:16.614: ISAKMP:(1070): processing DELETE payload. message ID = 
3081603117
.Apr  3 08:16:16.614: ISAKMP:(1070):peer does not do paranoid keepalives.

.Apr  3 08:16:16.614: ISAKMP:(1070):deleting SA reason "No reason" state (R) 
QM_IDLE       (peer 192.168.7.92)
.Apr  3 08:16:16.614: ISAKMP:(1070):deleting node -1213364179 error FALSE 
reason "Informational (in) state 1"
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: IPSEC(key_engine): got a queue event with 1 KMI 
message(s)
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: IPSEC(key_engine_delete_sas): rec'd delete notify from 
ISAKMP
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: IPSEC(key_engine_delete_sas): delete SA with spi 
0x3D3ED559 proto 50 for 192.168.7.92
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: crypto_engine: Pull flow statistics
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: crypto_engine_ipsec_flow_pull_statistics: calling 
driver
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: ISAKMP: set new node -1561337744 to QM_IDLE
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: crypto_engine: Generate IKE hash
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: crypto_engine: Encrypt IKE packet
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: ISAKMP:(1070): sending packet to 192.168.7.92 my_port 
500 peer_port 500 (R) QM_IDLE
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: ISAKMP:(1070):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: ISAKMP:(1070):purging node -1561337744
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: ISAKMP:(1070):Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL, 
IKE_PHASE1_DEL
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: ISAKMP:(1070):Old State = IKE_P1_COMPLETE  New State = 
IKE_DEST_SA

.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: ISAKMP:(1070):deleting SA reason "No reason" state (R) 
QM_IDLE       (peer 192.168.7.92)
.Apr  3 08:16:16.618: ISAKMP: Unlocking peer struct 0x3DB5A12C for 
isadb_mark_sa_deleted(), count 0
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: crypto engine: deleting IKE SA SW:70
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: crypto_engine: Delete IKE SA
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: IKE HA: Removing one interface using VIP 0.0.0.0
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: IKE HA: No database for VIP 0.0.0.0.  Cannot delete
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: IPSec HA: Removing one interface using VIP 0.0.0.0
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: IPSec HA: No database for VIP 0.0.0.0.  Cannot delete
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: ISAKMP:(1070):Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_PEER, IKE_MM_EXCH
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: ISAKMP:(1070):Old State = IKE_DEST_SA  New State = 
IKE_DEST_SA

.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: crypto_engine: Pull sadb-ivrf statistics
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: crypto_engine_ipsec_sadb_ivrf_pull_statistics: call 
driver
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: crypto_engine: Pull sadb-ivrf statistics, got error 
unsupported operation
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622:  ISAKMP: Failed to find peer index node to update 
peer_info_list
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: IPSEC(update_current_outbound_sa): updated peer 
192.168.7.92 current outbound sa to SPI 3D3ED559
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: IPSEC(delete_sa): deleting SA,
(sa) sa_dest= XX, sa_proto= 50,
sa_spi= 0x6D6766BE(1835493054),
sa_trans= esp-3des esp-sha-hmac , sa_conn_id= 2109
sa_lifetime(k/sec)= (250000/3600),
(identity) local= XX:0, remote= 192.168.7.92:0,
local_proxy= XX/ 255.255.255.255/17/1701,
remote_proxy= 192.168.7.92/255.255.255.255/17/1701
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: IPSEC(update_current_outbound_sa): updated peer 
192.168.7.92 current outbound sa to SPI 3D3ED559
.Apr  3 08:16:16.622: IPSEC(delete_sa): deleting SA,
(sa) sa_dest= 192.168.7.92, sa_proto= 50,
sa_spi= 0x3D3ED559(1027528025),
sa_trans= esp-3des esp-sha-hmac , sa_conn_id= 2110
sa_lifetime(k/sec)= (250000/3600),
```

(identity) local= XX:0, remote= 192.168.7.92:0,
     local_proxy= XX/255.255.255.255/17/1701,
    remote_proxy= 192.168.7.92/255.255.255.255/17/1701
   .Apr  3 08:16:16.622: crypto engine: deleting IPSec SA Onboard VPN:109
   .Apr  3 08:16:16.626: crypto_engine: Delete IPSec SA
   .Apr  3 08:16:16.626: crypto engine: deleting IPSec SA Onboard VPN:110
   .Apr  3 08:16:16.630: crypto_engine: Delete IPSec SA
   .Apr  3 08:16:16.634: %CRYPTO-5-SESSION_STATUS: Crypto tunnel is DOWN.  Peer 
   192.168.7.92:500       Id: 192.168.7.92
   ATVRouter#
   .Apr  3 08:16:16.634: ISAKMP: Deleting peer node by peer_reap for 
   192.168.7.92: 3DB5A12C
   .Apr  3 08:16:16.634: IPSEC(key_engine): got a queue event with 1 KMI 
   message(s)
   ATVRouter#
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.082: ISAKMP (0): received packet from 192.168.7.92 dport 500 
   sport 500 Global (N) NEW SA
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.082: ISAKMP: Created a peer struct for 192.168.7.92, peer 
   port 500
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.082: ISAKMP: New peer created peer = 0x23781594 peer_handle 
   = 0x80000065
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.082: ISAKMP: Locking peer struct 0x23781594, refcount 1 for 
   crypto_isakmp_process_block
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.082: ISAKMP: local port 500, remote port 500
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.082: ISAKMP: Find a dup sa in the avl tree during calling 
   isadb_insert sa = 3DA06FE8
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.082: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_PEER, IKE_MM_EXCH
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.082: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_READY  New State = IKE_R_MM1

.Apr  3 08:16:20.082: ISAKMP:(0): processing SA payload. message ID = 0
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.082: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.082: ISAKMP:(0): processing IKE frag vendor id payload
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.082: ISAKMP:(0):Support for IKE Fragmentation not enabled
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.082: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 69 
   mismatch
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP (0): vendor ID is NAT-T RFC 3947
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 123 
   mismatch
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID is NAT-T v2
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 194 
   mismatch
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 241 
   mismatch
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 184 
   mismatch
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 134 
   mismatch
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0):found peer pre-shared key matching 
   192.168.7.92
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0): local preshared key found
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP : Scanning profiles for xauth ...
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0):Checking ISAKMP transform 1 against priority 
   1 policy
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      encryption AES-CBC
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      keylength of 256
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      hash SHA
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      default group 20
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      auth pre-share
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      life type in seconds
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x0 0x70 0x80
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0):Encryption algorithm offered does not match 
   policy!
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0):atts are not acceptable. Next payload is 3
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0):Checking ISAKMP transform 2 against priority 
   1 policy
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      encryption AES-CBC
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      keylength of 128
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      hash SHA
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      default group 19
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      auth pre-share
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      life type in seconds
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x0 0x70 0x80
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0):Encryption algorithm offered does not match 
   policy!
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0):atts are not acceptable. Next payload is 3
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:(0):Checking ISAKMP transform 3 against priority 
   1 policy
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      encryption AES-CBC
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      keylength of 256
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      hash SHA
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      default group 14
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      auth pre-share
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      life type in seconds
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.086: ISAKMP:      life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x0 0x70 0x80
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0):Encryption algorithm offered does not match 
   policy!
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0):atts are not acceptable. Next payload is 3
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0):Checking ISAKMP transform 4 against priority 
   1 policy
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:      encryption 3DES-CBC
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:      hash SHA
   .Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:      default group 14
    .Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:      auth pre-share
.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:      life type in seconds

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:      life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x0 0x70 0x80

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0):Diffie-Hellman group offered does not match

policy!
.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0):atts are not acceptable. Next payload is 3

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0):Checking ISAKMP transform 5 against priority 1

policy
.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:      encryption 3DES-CBC

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:      hash SHA

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:      default group 2

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:      auth pre-share

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:      life type in seconds

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:      life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x0 0x70 0x80

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0):atts are acceptable. Next payload is 0

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0):Acceptable atts:actual life: 0

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0):Acceptable atts:life: 0

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0):Fill atts in sa vpi_length:4

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0):Fill atts in sa life_in_seconds:28800

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0):Returning Actual lifetime: 28800

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0)::Started lifetime timer: 28800.

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0): processing IKE frag vendor id payload

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0):Support for IKE Fragmentation not enabled

.Apr  3 08:16:20.090: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 69

mismatch

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP (0): vendor ID is NAT-T RFC 3947

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 123

mismatch

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID is NAT-T v2

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 194

mismatch

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 241

mismatch

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 184

mismatch

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 134

mismatch

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL,

IKE_PROCESS_MAIN_MODE

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_R_MM1  New State = IKE_R_MM1

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): constructed NAT-T vendor-rfc3947 ID

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to 192.168.7.92 my_port 500 
peer_port 500 (R) MM_SA_SETUP

.Apr  3 08:16:20.094: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.

.Apr  3 08:16:20.098: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL, IKE_PROCESS_COMPLETE

.Apr  3 08:16:20.098: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_R_MM1  New State = IKE_R_MM2

.Apr  3 08:16:20.106: ISAKMP (0): received packet from 192.168.7.92 dport 500

sport 500 Global (R) MM_SA_SETUP

.Apr  3 08:16:20.106: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_PEER, IKE_MM_EXCH

.Apr  3 08:16:20.106: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_R_MM2  New State = IKE_R_MM3

.Apr  3 08:16:20.106: ISAKMP:(0): processing KE payload. message ID = 0

.Apr  3 08:16:20.106: crypto_engine: Create DH shared secret

.Apr  3 08:16:20.162: ISAKMP:(0): processing NONCE payload. message ID = 0

.Apr  3 08:16:20.162: ISAKMP:(0):found peer pre-shared key matching 192.168.7.92

.Apr  3 08:16:20.162: crypto_engine: Create IKE SA

.Apr  3 08:16:20.162: crypto engine: deleting DH phase 2 SW:75

.Apr  3 08:16:20.162: crypto_engine: Delete DH shared secret

.Apr  3 08:16:20.162: ISAKMP:received payload type 20

.Apr  3 08:16:20.162: ISAKMP (1071): His hash no match - this node outside NAT

.Apr  3 08:16:20.162: ISAKMP:received payload type 20

.Apr  3 08:16:20.162: ISAKMP (1071): No NAT Found for self or peer

.Apr  3 08:16:20.162: ISAKMP:(1071):Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL,

IKE_PROCESS_MAIN_MODE

.Apr  3 08:16:20.162: ISAKMP:(1071):Old State = IKE_R_MM3  New State = IKE_R_MM3

.Apr  3 08:16:20.162: ISAKMP:(1071): sending packet to 192.168.7.92 my_port 500

peer_port 500 (R) MM_KEY_EXCH

.Apr  3 08:16:20.162: ISAKMP:(1071):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.

.Apr  3 08:16:20.166: ISAKMP:(1071):Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL,

IKE_PROCESS_COMPLETE

.Apr  3 08:16:20.166: ISAKMP:(1071):Old State = IKE_R_MM3  New State = IKE_R_MM4

.Apr  3 08:16:20.166: ISAKMP (1071): received packet from 192.168.7.92 dport 500

sport 500 Global (R) MM_KEY_EXCH

.Apr  3 08:16:20.166: crypto_engine: Decrypt IKE packet

.Apr  3 08:16:20.166: ISAKMP:(1071):Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_PEER, IKE_MM_EXCH

.Apr  3 08:16:20.166: ISAKMP:(1071):Old State = IKE_R_MM4  New State = IKE_R_MM5

.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071): processing ID payload. message ID = 0

.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP (1071): ID payload

```
    next-payload : 8

    type         : 1

    address      : 192.168.7.92

    protocol     : 0

    port         : 0

    length       : 12
```

.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(0):: peer matches *none* of the profiles

.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071): processing HASH payload. message ID = 0

.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: crypto_engine: Generate IKE hash

.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071):SA authentication status:

```
    authenticated
```

.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071):SA has been authenticated with 192.168.7.92

.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP: Trying to insert a peer

XX/192.168.7.92/500/,  and inserted successfully 23781594.

.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071):Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL, 
IKE_PROCESS_MAIN_MODE
.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071):Old State = IKE_R_MM5  New State = IKE_R_MM5

.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071):SA is doing pre-shared key authentication using id type ID_IPV4_ADDR
.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP (1071): ID payload
        next-payload : 8
        type         : 1
        address      : XX
        protocol     : 17
        port         : 500
        length       : 12
.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071):Total payload length: 12
.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: crypto_engine: Generate IKE hash
.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: crypto_engine: Encrypt IKE packet
.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071): sending packet to 192.168.7.92 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (R) MM_KEY_EXCH
.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071):Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL, IKE_PROCESS_COMPLETE
.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071):Old State = IKE_R_MM5  New State = IKE_P1_COMPLETE

.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071):Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL, IKE_PHASE1_COMPLETE
.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP:(1071):Old State = IKE_P1_COMPLETE  New State = IKE_P1_COMPLETE

.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP (1071): received packet from 192.168.7.92 dport 500 sport 500 Global (R) QM_IDLE
.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: ISAKMP: set new node 1 to QM_IDLE
.Apr  3 08:16:20.170: crypto_engine: Decrypt IKE packet
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: crypto_engine: Generate IKE hash
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071): processing HASH payload. message ID = 1
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071): processing SA payload. message ID = 1
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071):Checking IPSec proposal 1
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP: transform 1, ESP_AES
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:   attributes in transform:
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:      encaps is 2 (Transport)
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:      key length is 128
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:      authenticator is HMAC-SHA
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:      SA life type in seconds
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:      SA life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x0 0xE 0x10
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:      SA life type in kilobytes
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:      SA life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x3 0xD0 0x90
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071):atts are acceptable.
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: IPSEC(validate_proposal_request): proposal part #1
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: IPSEC(validate_proposal_request): proposal part #1,
  (key eng. msg.) INBOUND local= XX:0, remote= 192.168.7.92:0,
    local_proxy= XX/255.255.255.255/17/1701,
    remote_proxy= 192.168.7.92/255.255.255.255/17/1701,
    protocol= ESP, transform= NONE  (Transport),
    lifedur= 0s and 0kb,
    spi= 0x0(0), conn_id= 0, keysize= 128, flags= 0x0
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: IPSEC(ipsec_process_proposal): transform proposal not supported for identity:
    {esp-aes esp-sha-hmac }
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071): IPSec policy invalidated proposal with error 256
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071):Checking IPSec proposal 2
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP: transform 1, ESP_3DES
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:   attributes in transform:
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:      encaps is 2 (Transport)
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:      authenticator is HMAC-SHA
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:      SA life type in seconds
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:      SA life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x0 0xE 0x10
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:      SA life type in kilobytes
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:      SA life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x3 0xD0 0x90
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071):atts are acceptable.
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: IPSEC(validate_proposal_request): proposal part #1
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: IPSEC(validate_proposal_request): proposal part #1,
  (key eng. msg.) INBOUND local= XX:0, remote= 192.168.7.92:0,
    local_proxy= XX/255.255.255.255/17/1701,
    remote_proxy= 192.168.7.92/255.255.255.255/17/1701,
    protocol= ESP, transform= NONE  (Transport),
    lifedur= 0s and 0kb,
    spi= 0x0(0), conn_id= 0, keysize= 0, flags= 0x0
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071): processing NONCE payload. message ID = 1
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071): processing ID payload. message ID = 1
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071): processing ID payload. message ID = 1
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071):QM Responder gets spi
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071):Node 1, Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_PEER, IKE_QM_EXCH
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071):Old State = IKE_QM_READY  New State = IKE_QM_SPI_STARVE
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: crypto_engine: Generate IKE hash
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071):Node 1, Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL, IKE_GOT_SPI
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: ISAKMP:(1071):Old State = IKE_QM_SPI_STARVE  New State = IKE_QM_IPSEC_INSTALL_AWAIT
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: IPSEC(key_engine): got a queue event with 1 KMI message(s)
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: IPSEC(crypto_ipsec_create_ipsec_sas): Map found dyn-map
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: crypto_engine: Generate IKE QM keys
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: crypto_engine: Create IPSec SA (by keys)
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: crypto_engine: Generate IKE QM keys
.Apr  3 08:16:20.174: crypto_engine: Create IPSec SA (by keys)
.Apr  3 08:16:20.178: IPSEC(create_sa): sa created,
  (sa) sa_dest= XX, sa_proto= 50,
    sa_spi= 0x7315891C(1930791196),
    sa_trans= esp-3des esp-sha-hmac , sa_conn_id= 2111
    sa_lifetime(k/sec)= (250000/3600)
.Apr  3 08:16:20.178: IPSEC(create_sa): sa created,
  (sa) sa_dest= 192.168.7.92, sa_proto= 50,
    sa_spi= 0x8F7085B8(2406516152),
    sa_trans= esp-3des esp-sha-hmac , sa_conn_id= 2112
    sa_lifetime(k/sec)= (250000/3600)
.Apr  3 08:16:20.178:  ISAKMP: Failed to find peer index node to update peer_info_list
.Apr  3 08:16:20.178: ISAKMP:(1071):Received IPSec Install callback... proceeding with the negotiation
.Apr  3 08:16:20.178: %CRYPTO-5-SESSION_STATUS: Crypto tunnel is UP  .  Peer 192.168.7.92:500       Id: 192.168.7.92
ATVRouter#
.Apr  3 08:16:20.178: crypto_engine: Encrypt IKE packet
.Apr  3 08:16:20.178: ISAKMP:(1071): sending packet to 192.168.7.92 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (R) QM_IDLE
.Apr  3 08:16:20.178: ISAKMP:(1071):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
.Apr  3 08:16:20.178: ISAKMP:(1071):Node 1, Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_IPSEC, IPSEC_INSTALL_DONE
.Apr  3 08:16:20.178: ISAKMP:(1071):Old State = IKE_QM_IPSEC_INSTALL_AWAIT  New State = IKE_QM_R_QM2
.Apr  3 08:16:20.902: Before decryption:
0E9A1710:                       4500 00B02F21            E..0/!
0E9A1720: 00007F32 8DA7C0A8 075C5584 60CB7315  ...2.'@(.\U.`Ks.
0E9A1730: 891C0000 0001EFA6 247AF2C7 3279C1E2  ......o&$zrG2yAb
0E9A1740: A511DBA4 AC053704 024C               %.[$,.7..L       ...
.Apr  3 08:16:20.902: After decryption:
0E9A1720:                       4500 00912F21            E.../!
0E9A1730: 00007F11 8DE7C0A8 075C5584 60CB06A5  .....g@(.\U.`K.%
0E9A1740: 06A5007D 3DAEC802 00750000 00000000  .%.}=.H..u......
0E9A1750: 00008008 00000000 0001               ..........       ...
.Apr  3 08:16:21.034: ISAKMP (1071): received packet from 192.168.7.92 dport 500 sport 500 Global (R) QM_IDLE
.Apr  3 08:16:21.034: crypto_engine: Decrypt IKE packet
.Apr  3 08:16:21.034: crypto_engine: Generate IKE hash
.Apr  3 08:16:21.034: ISAKMP:(1071):deleting node 1 error FALSE reason "QM done (await)"
.Apr  3 08:16:21.034: ISAKMP:(1071):Node 1, Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_PEER, IKE_QM_EXCH
.Apr  3 08:16:21.034: ISAKMP:(1071):Old State = IKE_QM_R_QM2  New State = IKE_QM_PHASE2_COMPLETE
.Apr  3 08:16:21.034: IPSEC(key_engine): got a queue event with 1 KMI message(s)
.Apr  3 08:16:21.034: IPSEC(key_engine_enable_outbound): rec'd enable notify from ISAKMP
.Apr  3 08:16:21.034: crypto engine: updating MTU size of IPSec SA Onboard VPN:112
.Apr  3 08:16:21.034: crypto_engine: Set IPSec MTU
.Apr  3 08:16:21.034: IPSEC: Expand action denied, notify RP
.Apr  3 08:16:21.370: Before decryption:
ATVRouter#
0E77EF10:                       4500 00B02F36            E..0/6
0E77EF20: 00007F32 8D92C0A8 075C5584 60CB7315  ...2..@(.\U.`Ks.
0E77EF30: 891C0000 00024D72 BFA1217C F028FDAC  ......Mr?!!|p(},
0E77EF40: 126D1317 154D99D9 FE1D               .m...M.Y~.       ...
.Apr  3 08:16:21.370: After decryption:
0E77EF20:                       4500 00912F36            E.../6
0E77EF30: 00007F11 8DD2C0A8 075C5584 60CB06A5  .....R@(.\U.`K.%
0E77EF40: 06A5007D 3DAEC802 00750000 00000000  .%.}=.H..u......
0E77EF50: 00008008 00000000 0001               ..........       ...
ATVRouter#
.Apr  3 08:16:23.182: Before decryption:
0E872A90:                       4500 00B02F46            E..0/F
0E872AA0: 00007F32 8D82C0A8 075C5584 60CB7315  ...2..@(.\U.`Ks.
0E872AB0: 891C0000 000388AF CB251180 AD8DF624  ......./K%..-.v$
0E872AC0: 3E41D021 E42A3957 AB10               >AP!d*9W+.       ...
.Apr  3 08:16:23.182: After decryption:
0E872AA0:                       4500 00912F46            E.../F
0E872AB0: 00007F11 8DC2C0A8 075C5584 60CB06A5  .....B@(.\U.`K.%
0E872AC0: 06A5007D 3DAEC802 00750000 00000000  .%.}=.H..u......
0E872AD0: 00008008 00000000 0001               ..........       ...
ATVRouter#
.Apr  3 08:16:27.181: Before decryption:
0E85BE90:                       4500 00B02F4D            E..0/M
0E85BEA0: 00007F32 8D7BC0A8 075C5584 60CB7315  ...2.{@(.\U.`Ks.
0E85BEB0: 891C0000 00048C24 1EF1EE86 85AD43A7  .......$.qn..-C'
0E85BEC0: ACE56CC9 A3603B72 C3B7               ,elI#`;rC7       ...
.Apr  3 08:16:27.181: After decryption:
0E85BEA0:                       4500 00912F4D            E.../M
0E85BEB0: 00007F11 8DBBC0A8 075C5584 60CB06A5  .....;@(.\U.`K.%
0E85BEC0: 06A5007D 3DAEC802 00750000 00000000  .%.}=.H..u......
0E85BED0: 00008008 00000000 0001               ..........       ...
ATVRouter#
.Apr  3 08:16:35.181: Before decryption:
0E87C490:                       4500 00B02F55            E..0/U
0E87C4A0: 00007F32 8D73C0A8 075C5584 60CB7315  ...2.s@(.\U.`Ks.
0E87C4B0: 891C0000 000506C7 E739688F C70DF4DB  .......Gg9h.G.t[
0E87C4C0: 94F2096C 79CE037A B69C               .r.lyN.z6.       ...
.Apr  3 08:16:35.181: After decryption:
0E87C4A0:                       4500 00912F55            E.../U
0E87C4B0: 00007F11 8DB3C0A8 075C5584 60CB06A5  .....3@(.\U.`K.%
0E87C4C0: 06A5007D 3DAEC802 00750000 00000000  .%.}=.H..u......
0E87C4D0: 00008008 00000000 0001               ..........       ...

Debug shows that 2 phases of IPSec is success, but I still cannot connect via Windows built-in vpn client.

Comment: What errors are you getting on the Windows side?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a misconfiguration between yours hash algorithm :

The conf of your router :

```
...
crypto isakmp policy 20
encr 3des    
authentication pre-share    
group 2    
hash md5
...
```

And during the ISAKMP nego, your router receive a proposal with only SHA as signature algorithm:

```
Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):Hash algorithm offered does not match policy!    
Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):atts are not acceptable. Next payload is 0    
Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):no offers accepted!    
Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): phase 1 SA policy not acceptable! (local 85.132.96.203 remote 192.168.3.242)
```

Yours equipments must have common algo for the ISAKMP negociation.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the error(e.g. proposal not chosen, auth failed etc) your are getting when you are trying to connect you windows system with cisco gateway.
Also please provide ISAKMP messages for more detailed debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Windows side show this error:

Error 789: The L2TP connection attempt failed because the security layer encountered a processing error during initial negotiations with the remote computer.

On Cisco side:

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP (0): received packet from 192.168.3.242 dport 500 sport 500 Global (N) NEW SA

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP: Created a peer struct for 192.168.3.242, peer port 500

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP: New peer created peer = 0x3C770598 peer_handle = 0x8000001A

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP: Locking peer struct 0x3C770598, refcount 1 for crypto_isakmp_process_block

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP: local port 500, remote port 500

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):insert sa successfully sa = 3D862750

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_PEER, IKE_MM_EXCH

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_READY  New State = IKE_R_MM1

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): processing SA payload. message ID = 0

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): processing IKE frag vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):Support for IKE Fragmentation not enabled
Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 69 mismatch
Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP (0): vendor ID is NAT-T RFC 3947

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 123 mismatch

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID is NAT-T v2

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 194 mismatch

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 241 mismatch

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 184 mismatch

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 134 mismatch

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):found peer pre-shared key matching 192.168.3.242

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0): local preshared key found

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP : Scanning profiles for xauth ... L2TP-PROF

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):Checking ISAKMP transform 1 against priority 20 policy

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      encryption AES-CBC

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      keylength of 256

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      hash SHA

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      default group 20

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      auth pre-share

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      life type in seconds

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x0 0x70 0x80

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):Encryption algorithm offered does not match policy!

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):atts are not acceptable. Next payload is 3

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):Checking ISAKMP transform 2 against priority 20 policy

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      encryption AES-CBC

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      keylength of 128

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      hash SHA

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      default group 19

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      auth pre-share

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      life type in seconds

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x0 0x70 0x80

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):Encryption algorithm offered does not match policy!

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):atts are not acceptable. Next payload is 3

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):Checking ISAKMP transform 3 against priority 20 policy

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      encryption AES-CBC

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      keylength of 256

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      hash SHA

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      default group 14

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      auth pre-share

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      life type in seconds

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x0 0x70 0x80

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):Encryption algorithm offered does not match policy!

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):atts are not acceptable. Next payload is 3

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:(0):Checking ISAKMP transform 4 against priority 20 policy

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      encryption 3DES-CBC

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      hash SHA

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      default group 14

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      auth pre-share

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      life type in seconds

Mar 31 11:22:27.865: ISAKMP:      life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x0 0x70 0x80

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):Hash algorithm offered does not match policy!

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):atts are not acceptable. Next payload is 3
Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):Checking ISAKMP transform 5 against priority 
20 policy

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:      encryption 3DES-CBC

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:      hash SHA

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:      default group 2

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:      auth pre-share

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:      life type in seconds

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:      life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x0 0x70 0x80

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):Hash algorithm offered does not match policy!

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):atts are not acceptable. Next payload is 0

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):no offers accepted!

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): phase 1 SA policy not acceptable! (local 85.132.96.203 remote 192.168.3.242)

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP (0): incrementing error counter on sa, attempt 1 of 5: construct_fail_ag_init

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): Failed to construct AG informational message.

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to 192.168.3.242 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (R) MM_NO_STATE

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):peer does not do paranoid keepalives.

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):deleting SA reason "Phase1 SA policy proposal not accepted" state (R) MM_NO_STATE (peer 192.168.3.242)

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): processing IKE frag vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):Support for IKE Fragmentation not enabled

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 69 mismatch

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP (0): vendor ID is NAT-T RFC 3947

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 123 mismatch

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID is NAT-T v2

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 194 mismatch

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 241 mismatch

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 184 mismatch

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 134 mismatch

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP (0): FSM action returned error: 2

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL, IKE_PROCESS_MAIN_MODE

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_R_MM1  New State = IKE_R_MM1

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):deleting SA reason "Phase1 SA policy proposal not accepted" state (R) MM_NO_STATE (peer 192.168.3.242)

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP: Unlocking peer struct 0x3C770598 for isadb_mark_sa_deleted(), count 0

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP: Deleting peer node by peer_reap for 192.168.3.242: 3C770598

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: %CRYPTO-5-IKMP_SETUP_FAILURE: IKE SETUP FAILED for local:192.168.3.242 local_id:192.168.3.242 remote:85.132.96.203

remote_id:85.132.96.203 IKE profile:None fvrf:None fail_reason:Proposal failure fail_class_cnt:1

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: IKE HA: Removing one interface using VIP 0.0.0.0

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: IKE HA: No database for VIP 0.0.0.0.  Cannot delete

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: IPSec HA: Removing one interface using VIP 0.0.0.0

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: IPSec HA: No database for VIP 0.0.0.0.  Cannot delete

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL, IKE_PHASE1_DEL

Mar 31 11:22:27.869: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_R_MM1  New State = IKE_DEST_SA